# How to Select sql Database and copy and edit the figures

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio-2010, multi-database

Hi i would like to know how can i use a grid view select option and replicate the selected row and be able to edit the information in it as well and save/update it into another database

like if i click select,textboxes will fill up with the details of the selected row and i will be able to edit/add it like for example quantity and update it to another database

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: What do you mean, "Click select"? Please, make your question clear or it will be flagged as unclear

Comment: Do you mean to say that you got a table(table1) and then when you select a row in the grid(that fetches from table1) you need to edit/add details into it and then store it in another table (say table2)?And which all buttons you have in your codes?

Comment: i have done the web service and use an objectDataSource to retrieve data to the grid view i enabled selection and now i'm thinking by selecting the "Select" i want the system to copy the data into textboxes and allow me to edit it. like row "product, description, price" will copy the data to the textboxes and allow be to edit or add "quantity , "date" and update the new content into another database as the first table was from the supplier and i want to create a new table for the shop.